# using font awesome in Docbook generated HTML

Tags: xml, xslt, docbook, docbook-5, docbook-xsl

What steps should I take in creating a placeholder in docbook xml files that will use font awesome fonts in the generated HTML output.
Looking for xslt examples that use font awesome fonts in HTML output generated from DocBook.

Comment: Actually I think the approach I want to take is create an entity file for all the unicode characters representing the awesome fonts and then reference that entity file from a DOCTYPE  ENTITY statement in the xml header. Currently characters appear as a # pound symbol in the output. Guessing I need to add something to custom xsl layer that translates to correct awesome icon, not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: You also need to specify the FontAwesome font-family. To do this without changing the surrounding font, you'll end up adding a span anyway. If you use entity references, might as well put the entire markup in the entity: `<!ENTITY cake "<i class='fa fa-birthday-cake'></i>">` (Don't forget that you also need the FontAwesome font so the font-family can be resolved.)

Comment: Thanks for info it is getting me closer, however the docbook validation and  xsl files don't allow the i element. Appears that I will need to find which docbook element and attributes will be converted to the i element and class attribute in the HTML output by the docbook xsl, or attempt to customize the xsl.

Comment: <!ENTITY coffee "&lt;i class='fa fa-coffee'&gt;&lt;/i&gt;">    If I use Dec hex or html unicode the html output also contains the &lt; and &gt; instead of actual characters. If I use entity statement as you indicated, then the tag is empty - no fa class iinfo.

Comment: To clarify, no matter how I represent the less than and greater than symbols in the ENTITY declaration the xsl transformed html source contains &lt; and &gt;. If I manually change them to < and > for the i element the page is displayed correctly with awesome font. Is there a way to force the html output to contain < and >.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me what you get in the HTML when you leave the literal `<` and `>` in the declaration. Do you get any `i` element at all? Is it just the element with no `class` attribute?

Comment: If I leave the literal < and > in the declaration I get this in html       '<span style="color: red">&lt;i&gt;&lt;/i&gt;</span>'      If I replace < and > with &lt; and &gt; in the declaration the html source looks like    ' &lt;i class='fa fa-coffee'&gt;&lt;/i&gt;'     Need literal characters to appear in HTML source and it will work fine.  Also, since  <I> is not a valid docbook element, validation error appears. Need a way to pass through literal characters. Tried escaping with \ but did not work

Comment: That's because the XSLT doesn't have a template to handle the `i` element. How are you running the XSLT? What processor are you using? I have 2 possible ways to get this working.

Comment: If you have a xsl template that handles the i element, I could try adding it to my xsl custom layer. If not, I will attempt to create template. I am using Oxygen 16 and saxon processor, also from a command line using ant scripts and docbook webhelp xsl files. Even if a new xsl template handles i element - will < and > show up in html source.

Comment: I will go ahead and post both options as an answer. I'm testing with oxygen 15 so they should work for you. It will be a while before I can post though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully this answer isn't tl;dr. If you would rather me break this out into 3 separate answers, please let me know.

## Option 1

The first option is to use the HTML markup in the entity declaration like I first mentioned in the comments.

**Pros**

- XSLT 1.0 so minimal XSLT changes to docbook stylesheets

**Cons**

- `i` html element isn't valid so you'll have validation errors in your docs
- feels like a hack

**What you'll need to do:**

1. Change your entity declarations to look like this:

   ```
   <!ENTITY fa-birthday-cake "<i class='fa fa-birthday-cake' xmlns=''></i>">
   ```

   This is slightly different from what I had in my first comment. I added an empty namespace so that the `i` element wasn't automatically in the default namespace.
2. Add the link to the font-awesome css in the `head`. (I have it pointing to font-awesome locally.)

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
   ```

   For testing I modified `frameworks/docbook/xsl/html/profile-docbook.xsl`. I added the `link` around line 460 in the `match="*" mode="process.root"` template.
3. Add the template to match the `i` element so it doesn't get replaced.

   ```
   <xsl:template match="i">
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>
   ```

Example...

**Docbook Input**

```
<!DOCTYPE section [
<!ENTITY fa-birthday-cake "<i class='fa fa-birthday-cake' xmlns=''></i>">
]>
<section xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" version="5.0">
    <title>Section Template Title</title>
    <para>birthday cake: &fa-birthday-cake;</para>
</section>
```

**HTML Output** (using DocBook HTML transformation scenario)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <title>Section Template Title</title>
        <meta name="generator" content="DocBook XSL Stylesheets V1.78.1">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white" text="black" link="#0000FF" vlink="#840084" alink="#0000FF">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="titlepage">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="title" style="clear: both">
                        <a name="d56e3"></a>Section Template Title</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div></div>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <p>birthday cake: <i class='fa fa-birthday-cake'></i></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Rendererd HTML**

[image: Rendered HTML]

## Option 2

The second option is to use font awesome class in the entity declaration and use the `symbol` element, with a special `role` attribute, to hold the reference.

**Pros**

- XSLT 1.0 so minimal XSLT changes to docbook stylesheets
- `symbol` is a DocBook element so you shouldn't have validation issues

**Cons**

- `symbol` might not be available in all of the places you need to use a font-awesome icon
- feels like a hacky use of `symbol` (probably not as hacky as the first option though)

**What you'll need to do:**

1. Change your entity declarations to look like this:

   ```
   <!ENTITY fa-birthday-cake "fa-birthday-cake">
   ```
2. Add the link to the font-awesome css in the `head`. (I have it pointing to font-awesome locally.)

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
   ```

   For testing I modified `frameworks/docbook/xsl/html/profile-docbook.xsl`. I added the `link` around line 460 in the `match="*" mode="process.root"` template.
3. Add the template to match the `symbol` element with the 'fa' `role` and output the `i`. (`d` is bound to the `http://docbook.org/ns/docbook` namespace in profile-docbook.xsl)

   ```
   <xsl:template match="d:symbol[@role='fa']">
       <i class="fa {.}"></i>
   </xsl:template>
   ```

Example...

**Docbook Input**

```
<!DOCTYPE section [
<!ENTITY fa-birthday-cake "fa-birthday-cake">
]>
<section xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" version="5.0">
    <title>Section Template Title</title>
    <para>birthday cake: <symbol role="fa">&fa-birthday-cake;</symbol></para>
</section>
```

**HTML Output** (using DocBook HTML transformation scenario)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <title>Section Template Title</title>
        <meta name="generator" content="DocBook XSL Stylesheets V1.78.1">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white" text="black" link="#0000FF" vlink="#840084" alink="#0000FF">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="titlepage">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="title" style="clear: both">
                        <a name="d56e3"></a>Section Template Title</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div></div>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <p>birthday cake: <i class='fa fa-birthday-cake'></i></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Rendererd HTML**

[image: Rendered HTML]

## Option 3

The third option is to switch to XSLT 2.0 and use an `xsl:character-map`.

**Pros**

- Simple concept
- No additional markup needed in the docbook instance or in the entity declarations
- Feels good (not hacky)

**Cons**

- XSLT 2.0 so will need to use a 2.0 processor
- There might be additional XSLT changes after changing to the 2.0 processor. (For example, in my testing I had to remove 3 `exslt:node-set()` uses in profile-docbook.xsl.)

**What you'll need to do:**

1. Keep your entity declarations looking like this (based on your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055181/how-do-i-insert-fonts-as-an-entity-in-docbook):

   ```
   <!ENTITY fa-birthday-cake "&#xf1fd;">
   ```
2. Add the link to the font-awesome css in the `head`. (I have it pointing to font-awesome locally.)

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
   ```

   For testing I modified `frameworks/docbook/xsl/html/profile-docbook.xsl`. I added the `link` around line 460 in the `match="*" mode="process.root"` template.
3. Change the `xsl:stylesheet` version to 2.0.
4. Import the `xsl:character-map`.

   ```
   <xsl:include href="font-awesome.xsl"/>
   ```

   I've included an example "font-awesome.xsl". I have the complete version based on the font-awesome cheatsheet today (2015-05-06). Adding the entire contents pushes my answer over the character limit; let me know if you need it.

   ```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
       <xsl:character-map name="fa">
           <xsl:output-character string="&lt;i class='fa fa-birthday-cake'&gt;&lt;/i&gt;" character="&#xf1fd;"/>
       </xsl:character-map>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
5. Reference the character map (with `use-character-maps`) in the `xsl:output`.

   ```
   <xsl:output method="html" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="no" use-character-maps="fa"/>
   ```
6. Possible additional changes.

   Like mentioned in the "cons" section, you might need to make some changes to the docbook stylesheets depending on what processor you use. I used Saxon-HE 9.5.1.3. I did this by duplicating the DocBook HTML transformation scenario and changing the processor.

Example...

**Docbook Input**

```
<!DOCTYPE section [
<!ENTITY fa-birthday-cake "&#xf1fd;">
]>
<section xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" version="5.0">
    <title>Section Template Title</title>
    <para>birthday cake: &fa-birthday-cake;</para>
</section>
```

**HTML Output** (using the modified DocBook HTML transformation scenario)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <title>Section Template Title</title>
        <meta name="generator" content="DocBook XSL Stylesheets V1.78.1">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white" text="black" link="#0000FF" vlink="#840084" alink="#0000FF">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="titlepage">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <h2 class="title" style="clear: both">
                        <a name="d56e3"></a>Section Template Title</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div></div>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <p>birthday cake: <i class='fa fa-birthday-cake'></i></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Rendererd HTML**

[image: Rendered HTML]

Comment: This sounds great. I think this is something a lot company pubs depts could use. I would like a copy of your font-awesome.xsl file. I also experimented with option 2 using the docbook literal element, but decided it too may have limitations on where it could be used. I will try this out tomorrow. Thanks once again.

Comment: @JeffCunningham - If you send me an email (dhaley77 gmail) I will send it to you.

Comment: Ok sent you email from jeffcc. Thanks

Comment: I had to put a space before the closing </i> tag in the entity. If not there the html source leaves off the closing tag as puts in /> empty tag closure format. This causes multiple icons to appear in browser if </i> is missing.

Comment: @JeffCunningham - That shouldn't happen if the `xsl:output` method is html. Make sure you don't have any `xsl:output`'s that have a different method (or are missing a method attribute; the default is xml). Glad you have a workaround though; the offending `xsl:output` might actually be in the docbook xslt.

Comment: I noticed that using the span tag rather than the i tag in option one renders like it should in a browser when the tag is closed as an empty tag in the html source..

Comment: For option one, If I use the literallayout element in the entity declaration and assign fa fa-beer to the role attribute
and code in xsl to generate a custom class name 
    `<xsl:template match="d:literallayout" mode="class.value">`
    `<xsl:value-of select="@role"/>`
    `</xsl:template>`
I get this in html source
    `<div class="fa fa-beer"><p/></div><p>`
If I use markup element in entity declaration and role attribute set to font then class name does not change in html source
    `<span class="markup" />`

Comment: This is what I am going with for now until we move to an XSLT 2.0 processor.
Entity declaration:
    `<!ENTITY fa-beer "<markup role='fa fa-beer'></markup>">`
In xml file:
    `<para>&fa-beer; Assistant</para>`
In xsl file:
    `<xsl:template match="d:markup[@role]">`
    `     <span class="{@role}"></span>`
    `</xsl:template>`
HTML output:
    `<span class="fa fa-beer"/>`

Comment: Made slight change to first line in xsl match statement to match role attribute that contains fa- hopefully this will not interfere with other uses of the markup element.  
    `<xsl:template match="d:markup[contains(@role, 'fa-')]">`

Comment: @JeffCunningham - Something that might be a little safer is to add another role to `markup`. Something super unique; something like `<markup role='fa fa-beer [jcunningham]'></markup>` and then update your match: `d:markup[contains(@role, '[jcunningham]')]`. Then you can just strip out the extra role when you build your `span`. Something like: `normalize-space(substring-before(@role,'jcunningham'))`.

Comment: That was supposed to be `normalize-space(substring-before(@role,'[jcunningham]'))`

Comment: If possible, my next step is to have awesome fonts to appear in generated pdf output. I am reading up on how to add a font to the Apache FOP processor and adding statements to xsl custom layer, any thoughts on this subject would be appreciated.